# Fraudulent Smartpy Charges on my credit card

Tags: smartpy

For two months now I have been charged for Smartpy Smart Browser that I didn't ask for or sign up for. Can someone help me get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Hi Rick, this is something you should reach out to the smartpy team about. This is a site for asking for help with coding bugs/errors

Answer (score 0):

As said on Telegram, SmartPy is not charging you anything.

Perhaps it's SmartPay and not SmartPy.

Answer (score 0):

The same situation on my credit card statement: a charge by
"Smartpy*Smart Browser Ciudad de Mex"

(and yes it's Smartpy, not SmartPay) for $518.00 Mexican Pesos (about $25-$30 USD)

What is this? It's an absolutely unrecognized charge to my credit card.

Could there be 3rd parties using your name to make charges to credit cards?

Thanks for your comments.

EO

Answer (score 0):

In another post I saw some restaurants use this concept, mostly restaurants from ALSEA Group which are Domino's Pizza, Starbucks, Burger King, Chili's, P. F. Chang's, Italianni's, The Cheesecake Factory, Vips, Vips Smart, El Portón, Archies, Foster's Hollywood, Gino's, TGI Fridays, Foster's Hollywood Street, Ole Mole y Corazón de Barro.I was charged with 71.56 dollars on my debit card 2 months after I traveled to CDMX in my case the charge was from PF Chang's.